# How to do validation for 10 digit mobile number Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side-validation

```html
<div>
        <span id="mobile-valid">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
              Valid Mobile No
        </span>  
         <span id="mobile-invalid" >
           
                 Invalid mobile No
        </span>
      </div>
    <div>
     
          Mobile No
        </div>

      <div>
        <input id="mobile-num" type="text"/>
 
  </div>
```

How to do validation for 10 digit mobile number Using jQuery Ajax?Only numbers are allowed cannot use characters or alphanumeric characters.So how can i use jquery Ajax to do validation.I want to show on above input box that Invalid Email .and (dont want to show alert)

Comment: you can do with Regex search for regex which allow only numbers and not any other character

Comment: You do not need AJAX at all.

Comment: why not use input type number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for you...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#mobile-num").on("blur", function(){
        var mobNum = $(this).val();
        var filter = /^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;

          if (filter.test(mobNum)) {
            if(mobNum.length==10){
                  alert("valid");
              $("#mobile-valid").removeClass("hidden");
              $("#folio-invalid").addClass("hidden");
             } else {
                alert('Please put 10  digit mobile number');
               $("#folio-invalid").removeClass("hidden");
               $("#mobile-valid").addClass("hidden");
                return false;
              }
            }
            else {
              alert('Not a valid number');
              $("#folio-invalid").removeClass("hidden");
              $("#mobile-valid").addClass("hidden");
              return false;
           }
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="mobile">
   <div class="input">
  <div class="label">
    <div class="label-1">
   <span id="mobile-valid" class="hidden mob">
    <i class="fa fa-check pwd-valid"></i>Valid Mobile No
   </span>  
   <span id="folio-invalid" class="hidden mob-helpers">
    <i class="fa fa-times mobile-invalid"></i>Invalid mobile No
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
   <div class="label-2">
     Mobile No
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
   <input id="mobile-num" type="text" class="form-control form-change-element" />
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="#">
  Mobile number: <input type="text" name="mobile" pattern="^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$" title="Enter Valid mobile number ex.9811111111" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

starting with 9,8,7 you can add more as well.

you can test it using https://regex101.com/

Valid number are.

```
9883443344
09883443344
919883443344
0919883443344
+919883443344
+91-9883443344
0091-9883443344
+91 -9883443344
+91- 9883443344
+91 - 9883443344
0091 - 9883443344
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It contains the ten digits number validation for mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    Font-size: 10pt;
}
span
{
    font-weight:bold;
}

.san{
    height: 26px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;

}

  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtPhone').blur(function(e) {
        if (validatePhone('txtPhone')) {
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Valid Mobil Number');
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
        }
        else {
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('Invalid Mobile Number');
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});

function validatePhone(txtPhone) {
    var a = document.getElementById(txtPhone).value;
    var filter = /[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}/;
    if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
});//]]> 

</script>
</head>
<body>
  Phone Number: <input type='text' id='txtPhone' class="san" maxlength="10"/>
<span id="spnPhoneStatus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your jquery function

```
var mobileNum = $(this).val();
var validateMobNum= /^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
if (validateMobNum.test(mobileNum ) && mobileNum.length == 10) {
    alert("Valid Mobile Number");
}
else {
    alert("Invalid Mobile Number");
}
```

Comment: Please describe your solution, don't just post a block of code. This should provide more than a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

**try such thing**

```
    var value = "1234567.....";
    var NumberRegex = /^[0-9]*$/;
    if(value.length <= 10){
       if(NumberRegex.test(value)){
          //do whatever you want to
       }else{
          alert('invalid')
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Jquery validation for mobile number using regular expression**

*Validation include:*

1. 10 digit number only (No alphabets and No special characters)
2. Numbers starts from 6,7,8,9

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
   <label>Mobile Number:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control mobile-valid">

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.mobile-valid').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    // for 10 digit number only
    if ($this.val().length > 9) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }
     if (e.charCode < 54 && e.charCode > 47) {
         if ($this.val().length == 0) {
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
         } else {
           return true;
         }
     }
     if (regex.test(str)) {
       return true;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
     });
   });
   </script>  
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

For Demo Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shubhanshu/qkbchsag/23/)!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for validating your mobile number format. This function returns a boolean value.

```
function isValidMobileNumber(mobileNumber) {
  var mobileNumberPattern = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
  return mobileNumberPattern.test(mobileNumber);
}

if(isValidMobileNumber()){
//Valid mobile number format.
}else{
//Invalid mobile number format. 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var pattern= /^[0]*(\d{9})*\s*$/;
```

Use this pattern only to validate Sri Lankan numbers. In above code line only validate mobile number starting with 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
var contact = document.getElementById('contact').value;
      var result=/[&\][/\-\\|#=!+()$~%`^'":;*?<>{}]/g;
           contact.length = 10;
pattern =  /^([7-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$/;
                                
if(pattern.test(contact) ){
//true
                                
}else{
  document.getElementById("contact").value ="";
                                
alert('invalid');
                                
}
```